# Write dataframe to kafka pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a spark dataframe which I would like to write to Kafka. I have tried below snippet,

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers = util.get_broker_metadata())
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("foo", 1), ("bar", 2), ("baz", 3)], ('k', 'v'))
for row in df.rdd.collect():
    producer.send('topic',str(row.asDict()))
    producer.flush()
```

This works but problem with this snippet is this is not Scalable as every time collect runs, data will be aggregated on driver node and can slow down all operations.

As foreach operation on dataframe can run in parallel on worker nodes. I tried below approach.

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers = util.get_broker_metadata())
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("foo", 1), ("bar", 2), ("baz", 3)], ('k', 'v'))
def custom_fun(row):
    producer.send('topic',str(row.asDict()))
    producer.flush()

df.foreach(custom_fun)
```

This doesn't and gives pickling error. `PicklingError: Cannot pickle objects of type <type 'itertools.count'>`  Not able to understand the reason behind this error. Can anyone help me understand this error or provide any other parallel solution?

Comment: What is the Spark version and Python version? Do you get the same error when you run this code with clean session?

Comment: Hi, spark version is 2.1 and python is 2.7. Not sure what do you mean by clean session but I get same error everytime I launch job on yan using spark-submit.

Comment: I mean  that error looks unrelated to Kafka writes

Comment: @NachiketKate : you were able to find the answer? I am facing the same issue. Not able to write confluent kafka topic.

Answer (score 3):

The error you get looks unrelated to Kafka writes. Looks like somewhere else in your code you use `itertools.count` (AFAIK it is not used in Spark's source at all, it is of course possible that it comes with `KafkaProducer`) which is for some reason serialized with `cloudpickle` module. Changing Kafka writing code might have no impact at all. If `KafkaProducer` is the source of the error, you should be able to resolve this with `forachPartition`:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer


def send_to_kafka(rows):
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers = util.get_broker_metadata())
    for row in rows:
        producer.send('topic',str(row.asDict()))  
        producer.flush()

df.foreachPartition(send_to_kafka)
```

That being said:

> or provide any other parallel solution?

I would recommend using Kafka source. Include Kafka SQL package, for example:

```
spark.jars.packages  org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0
```

And:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_json, col, struct

(df 
    .select(to_json(struct([col(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns])))
    .write
    .format("kafka") 
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", botstrap_servers) 
    .option("topic", topic)
    .save())
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'll try this and will let you know.

Comment: With dataframe.write() I get nosuchmethoderror. Looks like version mismatch with spark, kafka, spark-sql-kafka.

Comment: `spark-sql-kafka` component has to match Spark and Scala version

Comment: how about sending just one column of dataframe to kafka instead of entire record?